# Why does the command ":g x" show all lines matching the last search?

Tags: search, command-line

I accidentally stumbled on a solution for a problem I had: I wanted to get an overview over all occurrances of the word under the cursor, after I used `#` to find them individually.

For some reason I guessed the command `:g %` and it did what I wanted. But I could not find an explanation of this, neither by reading `:help :g` nor `:help g` nor `:help %` nor `:help pattern` nor `:help cword`.

I experimented some more with this and I figured out

- that it had nothing to do with the cursor position and it would just repeat the last search,
- that I could replace the `%` with *any* single character (or at least, all that I tried worked), but there had to be one, and there had to be at least one space between `:g` and that character.

For example, `:g a`, `:g x`, `:g #`, `:g  c` all worked.

Typing one more character would use this as a start of a new search apparently.

Where can I find the documentation for this invocation? `:help :g` shows `:g/{pattern}/[cmd]` and does say that the `/` can be replaced by a different character, so I figured it could be a space, but then the syntax should be

```
:g<space>{pattern}<space>[cmd]
```

and I understand that the default `cmd` is `:p` which prints the matching lines, but I still don't understand why the last search pattern is inserted automatically and what the relevance of that trailing other character (`%`, `a`, `x` above) is.

I'm using Vim 8.2.2434.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it:

```
:g[global] /{pattern}/ [cmd]
```

1. You can have spaces between the `global` keyword and the pattern separator
2. The pattern separator can be any non alphanumeric character (except `\`, `|` or `"`)
3. The ending pattern separator is optional if not cmd is to be specified
4. If the pattern is empty the last pattern (`/` register) is used
5. If the cmd is not specified `p` (print) is used

With these rules `:g#` is equivalent to `:g##p` or `:g//p` or `:g#`<kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd>`/#p`

Comment: Remark: on Vim 8.2  and later `:g a` is not working with Vim 8.1 it is working.